# could not access my esxi server from my same network

Tags: router, esxi, adsl

I configured a server as Esxi 6.7 but I could not access it from my home network, the ESXi server can ping the default gateway but no other device can ping it or vice versa 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more details. What is the IP range? How are they physically connected? Etc.

Answer (score -1):

the problem was that "Enable MultiAP Isolation" was checked (in Setup -> Wireless -> Wireless Basic) which was blocking cross access/ping
D-Link router